# How to scale this set of points?

Tags: algorithms

I have a set of 8 points: `[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]`
they are x y pairs. We see below that `easeIn_right` has start point of `0, 0` and end point `0.5, 0.5`. So this was scaled to have end point of `1, 1` by multiplying each value by 2, this makes sense, this results in `easeIn_right2`.

However I can't figure out how they scaled `easeOut_right` so that its start point is `0, 0`. The scaled version is seen below as `easeOut_right2`. Please help.

Here is the data:

```
var easeIn_right = [0, 0, 0.21, 0, 0.355, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5];
var easeOut_right = [0.5, 0.5, 0.645, 0.75, 0.79, 1, 1, 1];
// Scaled
var easeIn_right2 = [0, 0, 0.42, 0, 0.71, 0.5, 1, 1]
var easeOut_right2 = [0, 0, 0.29, 0.5, 0.58, 1, 1, 1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a coordinate normalization: The smallest coordinate is mapped to 0 and the largest to 1. This is done by a combination of translation and scaling.

Translation vector:
$$ T = (-x_{min}, -y_{min})$$
Scaling factors:
$$ S_x = \frac{1}{x_{max}-x_{min}}$$
$$ S_y = \frac{1}{y_{max}-y_{min}})$$

$\hat{x}_i = (x_i + T_x) \cdot S_x$
$\hat{y}_i = (y_i + T_y) \cdot S_y$

**Example:**

$$x_{min} = 0.5, \ \ \  x_{max} = 1, \ \ \ x_1 = 0.645$$
$$\hat{x}_1 = (x_1 - x_{min}) \cdot \frac{1}{x_{max}-x_{min}} = (0.645- 0.5) \cdot 2 = 0.29$$

Comment: Thanks very much man can you please work out an example of getting from `0.645` to `0.29` I tried doing some quick work and botched it, but only spent a minute :P